# Executing two POST Requests together

Tags: reactjs, api, express

I can't figure out how to post both of these request. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
app.post("/api", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let response = await axios.post("/schedules/shifts", {
      ...req.body
    });
    let response2 = await axios.post("/schedules/shiftsSchedule", {
      ...req.body
    });

    res.status(201).json(response.data || response2.data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No. It would only execute one of the two post request.

Comment: Randomly or just the first one?

Comment: ...the first one

Answer (score 0):

JS is a single thread language and technically you can't execute two things at the same time...

However, you are using `await` which makes the async calls in sync manner and executes the subsequent code one after the another. Thus you are waiting for the first request to get completed and then the next request starts to process...

So you could use thenables or somethings like this

```
app.post("/api", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let response = axios.post("/schedules/shifts", {
      ...req.body
    });
    let response2 = axios.post("/schedules/shiftsSchedule", {
      ...req.body
    });
    const responseArr = await Promise.all([response, response2]);
    const data = responseArr.map((res) => res.data))[0]
    res.status(201).json(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you share your code on  codesand box or anything similar?